Rename tag minifigures -> minifigs
While minifigures may be the 'correct' term, I've never come across anyone who uses that term, instead, everyone uses minifigs, and as such the tag should be renamed. Thoughts? 

"Minifig" is simply a short form. It started off as "minifigure".

Are we talking about the collectables product line Minifigures, or the more general "Mini Figures" that are found in the Pick-a-brick selector?

Do we care about that distinction?

the keyword must be minifigure as spaces are not allowed. minifig and mini figure should be considered synonims.

@jfyelle I know, that's what hyphens are for ;) It's just that Joe was using as justification "the official product line is minifigures" but that is the collectable packets, rather than the generic term for the figures. That said, as we're hoping to catch google searches for "minifig", we won't do that if there's a hyphen ;)
